# response.redirect not working in chrome or firefox

Tags: asp.net

i have a problem .i'm grateful to answer.

i have a Gridview that included a button at one its column (inside itemtemplate).

i wrote a program inside Gridview rowcommand event for button that used response.redirect to self page.
but this response.redirect not working at chrome or firefox.
but working in IE correctly.

Comment: Please clarify _"redirect to self page"_ or add your code. In _ASP.Net Web Forms_ the standard action is a `POST`back ("to self") so unsure what "redirect to self" implies....

Comment: Yes, as EdSF pointed, please clarify exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Response.Redirect("Default3.aspx#3");//Default3.aspx#3 is current page

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the browser type/name like

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities bc = Request.Browser;
string bname = bc.Browser;
```

Then check if `bname` contains words like `firefox/chrom` (use a `if` condition) then redirect through JS client script like, else use `response.redirect`

```
        string PageUrl = "http://www.someurl.com";

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "someKeyRedir",
        "window.location.href = '" + PageUrl + "';", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm grateful to answer. my code is:

```
public void G2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)// in GridView,each button that be clicked,call this Gridview event 
{
    if (e.CommandName == "edit")//if this condition was true , 
    {
        Session.Remove("type");
        Session.Add("taskReport_id",e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        Response.Redirect("Default3.aspx#3");
      }  
    }
```

I tried below but this not working also

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", "window.location.href='Default3.aspx#3';", true);
```